# Finiteness of the intersection multiplicity of plane algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, local-rings

Hello guys i am trying to solve  excerise 2.7 page 14 from Gathmann notes https://agag-gathmann.math.rptu.de/class/curves-2023/curves-2023-c2.pdf

[image]

Definition

[image]

About (a) : Stuck here.Not sure how to use the curves not having common component at the origin.

About (b) : If the base field was the complex numbers i could use (a) to show the power series of a an element in K(x,y) has finite terms in the quotient,so  i could get a polynomial representative  that way.But since the field is random not sure how..maybe use geometric series?

About (c): i can show using (b) and the form of the representative that the quotient is spanned by finite amount of elements,so as a K-vector space it should have finite dimension.

Any hints that could point me to the right direction (especially about (a)) would be welcome.

Comment: If the two curves have no common component, what do you know about their intersection?

Comment: That their intersection V(F,G) should be finite?

Comment: (a) should be an application of the strong Hilbert Nullstellensatz. If $V(F,G) = \{0\}$, then you can apply it directly, as $x$ and $y$ vanish on all points of $V(F,G)$. If $V(F,G)$ consists of  more points, you have to get rid of them first by localizing $k[x,y]$ at a finite number of polynomials, which do not vanish on the additional points.

Comment: is there an elementary way to show this?We have not covered Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.